# Motherboard won't boot up after windows 10 network driver installation

Tags: windows, boot, drivers, motherboard, cmos

So after installing windows 10, the computer was working fine and I was able to use it and all but when we went to install the `network driver for windows 10`, it froze and then turned off.

I've got the following motherboard: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Fatal1ty%20B85%20Killer/

Have tried resetting CMOS and taking pin out. Any ideas?

Comment: post your solution as answer and mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed:

Weirdest thing. Simply pulled ram in and out and it started working again. Must have been a weird glitch because my computer was completely bricked until I pulled the `RAM` in and out.